# Number of ordered quadruples sets

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm trying to tackle the following question, but got no clue how to do so (I know it is not very popular not showing any effort, but this time I really don't know what to do).

Iv'e seen a solution that used inclusion-exclusion, but it seems to be incorrect and I don't understand how it is related to inclusion-exclusion.

> Find the number of ordered quadruples $(A,B,C,D)$ where $A,B,C,D$ are sets included in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $A \cup B \cup C \cup D=\{1,2,...,n\}$

Please explain any reasoning of solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use inclusion-exclusion:

Each element $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ must be in at least one of the sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.  Thus we may choose any nonempty subset of $\{A,B,C,D\}$ for which $i$ is an element of the chosen sets.  There are $15$ ways to do this since there are $15$ nonempty subsets of $\{A,B,C,D\}$.  Since we have to do this for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, there are $15^n$ ways to complete the process.

[By the way, I think this should be the same as the inclusion-exclusion solution to this problem, which I believe is $2^{4n}-{n\choose 1}2^{4(n-1)}+{n\choose2}2^{4(n-2)}-...=(16-1)^n$ by the binomial theorem.]

Comment: you just put up so much in so few lines, I had to read it three times to understand what you were saying, perfect!

Comment: @ADG: Thanks, I think.  :-)

Comment: @paw88789, thanks for your solution, I have only one question. Let's say that $1$ is in the sets A,B,C, hence the relevant nonempty subsets of ${A,B,C,D}$ are $\{A\},\{B\},\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{B,C\},\{A,B,C\}$, i.e only 7 nonempty sets. How is there 15 ways to choose?

Comment: @Galc127: As long as $1$ is in any nonempty combination of the sets $A, B, C, D$, it will be in $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$.  There are $15$ such combinations: $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$, $CD$, $ABC$, $ABD$, $ACD$, $BCD$, $ABCD$.  (Those are the $15$ choices referred to in my answer.)